# IBM mobilefirst http Adapter unable to access pdf attachment

Tags: cordova, pdf, ibm-mobilefirst, soap-client, worklight-adapters

i am trying to access the web service which having the method PDFattachment , i implemented HTTP adapter and  try to access the attachment but i am not getting proper attachment file ,returnedContentType : 'plain', and contentType:'application/pdf',here is the screenshots of the soap UI and adapter responseenter image description here

[image: web service output with file as inline attachment][image: worklight http adapter response]
please suggest  how to access the pdf attachment by the worklight adapter

**Adapter Code:**

```
function getInvoicePdfFile(prj_no, drft_No) {
    var request = 'soaprequest with parameters';
    var input = {
        method: 'POST',
        returnedContentType: 'plain',
        path: clintinvoicePath,
        headers: {
            SOAPAction: 'SoapAction end point',
            Authorization: authorisationPassword
        },
        body: {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'application/pdf',
        }
    };
    var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: please share your adapter code.

Comment: Hi Yoel please find the adapter code here

Comment: function getInvoicePdfFile(prj_no,drft_No) {
 var request = 'soaprequest with parameters';
 var input = {
     method : 'POST',
     returnedContentType : 'plain',
     path : clintinvoicePath,
     headers: {SOAPAction: 'SoapAction end point',
      Authorization: authorisationPassword 
     },
     body : {
      content: request.toString(),
      
      contentType:'application/pdf',
      
     } 
 };
 var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input); 
 return  result;
}

Comment: @LingarajSajjan, have you made any progress in this question?

Comment: we have done by alternative way like, converted the pdf data into base64 data from backend then used pdf.js plugin at the front end to convert base64 to pdf page, @IdanAdar

Comment: Thanks @LingarajSajjan, can you please write the above as an Answer to the question instead of a comment?

Comment: but still we are looking better option that can access pdf attachments directly inseted of base64 convertion its having performance issue @IdanAdar

Comment: That's fine to still look for alternatives, however this is one solution and should be written as an answer... please do not leave questions unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

While not best solution around, one solution that solved the problem was to encode the PDF data to base64 and then using pdf.js to decode the base64 string back into a PDF file and display it.